# 'Back link' won't work

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, navigation

In the middle of creating my first ever website.

I'd like to create a back link; like one you would get on any browser to take the user back to the previous page.

I need this because I won't always know what page they came from to get to that one.

I'm using this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function goBack()
  {
  window.history.back()
  }
</script>


<a href="#" onclick="goBack()" />Go Back</a>
```

You can see it here http://www.oilysart.com/89.html but there's no hyperlink showing and clicking doesn't do what I wish it to.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```javascript
<script language="javascript">
function goback(){
    history.back();
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="Go Back" onClick="goback()">
```

Comment: Thanks vogo. Changed it to this and works perfect and even looks better. You're a star

Answer (score 0):

you've closed your opening `<a>` tag. remove the / from the opening tag.

```
<a href="#" onclick="goBack()">Go Back</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You closed the `<a>` tag here:

```
<a href="#" onclick="goBack()" />
```

Change it to a non-closed `<a>` tag like so:

```
<a href="#" onclick="goBack()">Go Back</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works good, but one of the other divs is positioned *over* the link (id="Object8290"), hence you can't even click the link. If you remove some of the `<br>`s from the div, it should work.

Also this syntax is wrong:

```
<a href="#" onclick="goBack()" />Go Back</a>
```

should be

```
<a href="#" onclick="goBack()">Go Back</a>
```

Comment: Ok I changed what you've said and I've got a hyperlink that works with mouseover but clicking doesn't send me back still?

Answer (score 0):

> Ok I changed what you've said and I've got a hyperlink that works with
>   mouseover but clicking doesn't send me back still?

The problem you were encountering resulted from the fact that you were applying the JavaScript action to a hyperlink, so the linking behavior was taking precedence over the function behavior. It's fine to put this on a link if you really want to (a button would, of course, be better, as I think you discovered), but you've got to make sure that you're canceling the actual link action by returning false from your function and conveying that to the onclick event. Basically:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function goBack() {
        history.back();
        return false;
    }
</script>
<a href="" onclick="return goBack();">Go Back</a>
```